# Some product but diffrent attribute for each store view

Tags: magento-1.9, database, attributes, backend, pricing

We have many products in our store.

For each state in **Germany** we have a special product attribute and a different price.

User visit our website. Next step is to select the location/state in a popup.
Now we need to show the selected store with the correct attribute.

How we can manage the attribute and price depending on the selection?

**The Problem is** the price attribute we can only set to global view.

Comment: have you chek my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that it would be possible for you to use a Custom Option.

You can use the example here: http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/select-default-value-for-product-custom-option-in-magento/

But you go one step further by hiding or preventing the user from changing the form value to the other options (CSS/JS).

Answer (score 1):

You can set different currency depend on your store .

Follow this below steps for doing it.

1. In your Magento admin go to System > Manage Stores
2. Click  on Main Website Store  under the Store Name (if there are several  ones, click any of them)
3. On the next page under Store Information select a different language in the Default Store View drop-down list.
4. Click Save Store.
5. Now every time you are opening the your site, it’s going to be in the language  you selected.
6. You can change the default  language for the backend by going to System -> Configuration -> General -> Locale options.

**Setup Currency**

1. In admin panel, go to Admin > System > Configuration > Currency Set up.
2. Select currency that you want to be default from your base currency drop down.
3. Select the same currency in the Default Display Currency drop down and from the Allowed Currencies list.
4. Click Save Config.
5. The frontend display currency should be different if you check out your site.

For more detail you can check below tutorial

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-default-language-and-currency.html#gref